# Show active tickets in Trac wiki home page

Tags: trac, bug-tracking, bug-tracker

in my trac installation I'm looking for a way to show Active tickets in a section of the homepage. How could I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [TicketQuery Macro](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracQuery#UsingtheTicketQueryMacro) does what you want. For example add the following to the wiki page to get all open tickets sorted by ticket#:

```
[[TicketQuery(status=new|assigned|reopened|accepted&order=id)]]
```

Comment: If prefer `!closed`: `[[TicketQuery(format=table&status=!closed)]]` That way if a new non-closed status is added, it will be included.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd want to look into writing a [trac plugin](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment).  There's an example on [Trac Hacks](http://trac-hacks.org/) that seems like it might be a good starting point for what you're looking to do: [Watchlist Plugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/WatchlistPlugin)